# Swift: border on UICollectionViewCell for some sides

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

For an app I am currently building I need a grid like `UICollectionView` with 3x3 `UICollectionViewCell`'s displayed. The `UICollectionView` will have the same width as the screen, and therefore I want a border only shown on the right and bottom side of the `UICollectionViewCell`. It would have to look like this:

```
    -----------------------
     cell1 | cell4 | cell7
    -----------------------
     cell2 | cell5 | cell8
    -----------------------
     cell3 | cell6 |
    -----------------------
```

I think it would work if I could somehow draw a line on the bottom of an invisible `UICollectionView` header, and the same on the `UICollectionView` footer (a line on the top). An then for each `UICollectionViewCell` I could draw the missing lines.

However I don't know how to do this, and could not find anything on the subject that worked (somewhat) the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a view representing the line in your cell subclass. That is not the best performing solution, but sufficient in most cases, plus you do not need to write any code. In your `datasource` method you could then set this line as `hidden` or not based on the index path.

E.g., if you do not want a line on the right if it is the third cell in a row, do something like

```
cell.rightBorder.hidden = indexPath.item % 3 == 0
```

Comment: Thanks @Mundi for the suggestion, but I want my line to be 0.5 wide so the solution with the view is not possible I think. Have another idea? I am now looking into the drawRect method in the Custom Class of the UICollectionViewCell but I don't have the NSIndexPath there...

Comment: Why not possible? You can dimension the view to be 0.5 points wide. `drawRect` is also fine, but this is much less code.

Comment: Isn't the minimum width of a view in interface builder not 1 point? I cannot seem to change it to 0.5

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by subclassing the cell and overriding drawRect. There you can draw a bottom and right border.

Comment: Ok, makes sense.. But how can I see which cell I am in, and then check if it has a 'neighbouring cell' to know when and where to draw the lines?